# How to detect an overflow in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, overflow

I just wonder if there is some convenient way to detect if overflow happens to any variable of any default data type used in a C++ program during runtime? By convenient, I mean no need to write code to follow each variable if it is in the range of its data type every time its value changes. Or if it is impossible to achieve this, how would you do?

For example,

```
float f1=FLT_MAX+1;
cout << f1 << endl;
```

doesn't give any error or warning in either compilation with "gcc -W -Wall" or  running.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I would speculate that you could possible set up an interrupt handler to do it? Assuming that overflow actually generates an interrupt. As you can tell, I'm merely speculating here, hence adding it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: is it not better to write code that prevents (or makes them harder to happen) overflows rather than trying to catch it happening in the act?  I am just throwing the thought out.

Comment: @Jay: not necessarily. Especially in floating-point, there are some classes of algorithms for which overflow is very, very rare, and the added computational expense of preventing it entirely is very large. In a performance critical situation, you might rather use the fast algorithm that doesn't prevent overflow, and replay the one calculation in a million for which overflow occurs using the careful, slower algorithm that prevents overflow.

Comment: @stephentyrone ... I sit corrected, thanks. :-)

Comment: If you're really lucky, your IEEE float implementation lets you set the overflow mode, so you can configure at runtime whether overflows clamp at infinity, or give a hardware exception. For example, http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Setting-up-your-IEEE-environment.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect unsigned integer multiply overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-do-i-detect-unsigned-integer-multiply-overflow)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using [boosts numeric conversion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/index.html) which gives you `negative_overflow` and `positive_overflow` exceptions ([examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html#boost_numericconversion.improved_numeric_cast__.examples)).

Comment: +1.  not only does this seem like a good solution, but I learned that "negative overflow" and "underflow" are not the same thing... silly me.

Answer (score 4):

Your example doesn't actually overflow in the default floating-point environment in a IEEE-754 compliant system.

On such a system, where float is 32 bit binary floating point, FLT_MAX is 0x1.fffffep127 in C99 hexadecimal floating point notation.  Writing it out as an integer in hex, it looks like this:

```
0xffffff00000000000000000000000000
```

Adding one (without rounding, as though the values were arbitrary precision integers), gives:

```
0xffffff00000000000000000000000001
```

But in the default floating-point environment on an IEEE-754 compliant system, any value between

```
0xfffffe80000000000000000000000000
```

and

```
0xffffff80000000000000000000000000
```

(which includes the value you have specified) is rounded to FLT_MAX.  No overflow occurs.

Compounding the matter, your expression (FLT_MAX + 1) is likely to be evaluated at compile time, not runtime, since it has no side effects visible to your program.

Answer (score 3):

In situations where I need to detect overflow, I use `SafeInt<T>`.  It's a cross platform solution which throws an exception in overflow situations.

```
SafeInt<float> f1 = FLT_MAX;
f1 += 1; // throws
```

It is available on codeplex

- http://www.codeplex.com/SafeInt/

Comment: SafeInt is must have library, is there an equivalent for floats? `SafeInt<float>` doesn't compile..

Answer (score 2):

Back in the old days when I was developing C++ (199x) we used a tool called Purify. Back then it was a tool that instrumented the object code and logged everything 'bad' during a test run.
I did a quick google and I'm not quite sure if it still exists.

As far as I know nowadays several open source tools exist that do more or less the same.
Checkout electricfence and valgrind.

Comment: Purify exists; it is part of IBM's [Rational](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) toolset now.

Answer (score 0):

Clang provides `-fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow` and `-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow`.

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-code-generation